# Case insensitive comparison in Bash

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm trying to write a comparison in a while statement that's case insensitive.  Basically, I'm simply trying to shorten the following to act on a yes or no question prompt to the user ...

```
while[ $yn == "y" | $yn == "Y" | $yn == "Yes" | $yn == "yes" ] ; do
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: consider to use regex, could be shorter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case Insensitive comparision of strings in Shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728683/case-insensitive-comparision-of-strings-in-shell-script)

Comment: Notice that there is a missing space before the opening `[`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
shopt -s nocasematch
while [[ $yn == y || $yn == "yes" ]] ; do
```

or :

```
shopt -s nocasematch
while [[ $yn =~ (y|yes) ]] ; do
```

### Note

- `[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals
  Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.
- The `=~` operator of `[[` evaluates the left hand string against the right hand extended regular expression (ERE). After a successful match, `BASH_REMATCH` can be used to expand matched groups from the pattern. Quoted parts of the regex become literal. To be safe & compatible, put the regex in a parameter and do `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`

Comment: Will the `shopt -s nocasematch` cause my sed-based find and replaces to also be case insensitive?

Comment: Try it, that will takes you 15 seconds =)

Comment: for the regex one, better with `^..$`  e.g. `yn="noyesno"`

Comment: I actually wanted all characters to be case insensitive but I figured just asking with the few combinations I specified would be sufficient to infer from there.  Your original `while[[ $yn =~ (y|yes) ]]` seemed to work perfectly.

Comment: or `[[ $yn =~ y(es)? ]]`; the parens in `(y|yes)` aren't really needed, by the way.

Answer (score 16):

No need to use shopt or regex.  The easiest and quickest way to do this (as long as you have Bash 4):

```
if [ "${var1,,}" = "${var2,,}" ]; then
  echo "matched"
fi
```

All you're doing there is converting both strings to lowercase and comparing the results.

Comment: I've just tried that and it worked. I am unsure though how. Could you link to the documentation or at least tell how that structure is named?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs the `${my_variable,,}` syntax is bash parameter expansion.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion and scroll to the bottom of that section for the case conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer that uses extended patterns instead of regular expressions:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
shopt -s extglob
while [[ $yn = y?(es) ]]; do
  ...
done
```

Note that starting in version 4.1, `bash` always uses extended patterns inside the `[[ ... ]]` conditional expression, so the `shopt` line is no necessary.

Comment: I think your '?' is in the wrong spot in your regex. That will match "yes" or "es" but not "y".

Comment: It's not a regular expression; it's an extended pattern. The `y` matches itself; `?(es)` matches zero or one occurrence of the pattern `es`.

Answer (score 1):

try this one too:

```
 [[ $yn =~ "^[yY](es)?$" ]]
```

Comment: And if I want the "es" to be case insensitive as well I could put `[[ $yn =~ "^[yY][eE][sS]" || $yn == [yY] ]]?  I want to be able to accept "yEs" and "YeS" and all other combinations of case.

Comment: @sputnick take a look the question and example, only `y` is case insensitive, `es` part is only lower case... that what I understood..

Comment: @user2150250 then I suggest you before going into the while loop, do a 'tr`, make the value all in lower/upper case. then you could save some effort. You could just compare if it equals `y` or `yes` (if in lower case)

Comment: If you are using Bash v4.x+ you can perform string case conversion without invoking tr. `yn=${yn,,}; [[ $yn =~ ^yes ]]`

Comment: Quoting the right-hand side here actually suppresses interpretation as a regex (except for Bash 3.1 and older), so this wouldn't work as is for non-ancient Bash. The safe way is to declare the regex in a separate variable and then use that one in `[[ ]]`, unquoted.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `grep -E` or `egrep` for short:

```
while egrep -iq '^(y|yes)$' <<< $yn; do
  your_logic_here
done
```

Here you have explanations from `grep` manual:

> -i, --ignore-case
>
> Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.  (-i is specified by POSIX.)
>
> -q, --quiet, --silent
>
> Quiet; do not write anything to standard output.  **Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found**, even if an error was detected.  Also see the -s or --no-messages option.  (-q is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: This works, but it's much more efficient to use bash-internal syntax than calling an external program. The difference won't matter for an interactive script, of course, since the human in the loop is orders of magnitude slower than the external process, but I still prefer using my scripting language's own syntax when it's easy enough.