# Case insensitive comparision in If condition

Tags: bash, shell

I have this csv file and i need to count the number of rows which satisfies the condition that the row entry is betwen a certain year range and the artist_name matches the name argument. But the string matching should be case insensitive. How do i achieve that in the if loop..

I am a beginner, so please bear with me

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"
artist="$2" 
from_year="$(($3-1))"
to_year="$(($4+1))"
count=0

while IFS="," read arr1 arr2 arr3 arr4 arr5 arr6 arr7 arr8 arr9 arr10 arr11 ; do

if [[ $arr11 -gt $from_year ]] && [[ $arr11 -lt $to_year ]] && [[ $arr7  =~ $artist ]]; then
count=$((count+1))
fi

done < "$file"
echo $count
```

The $arr7 =~ $artist part is where i need to make the modification

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case Insensitive comparision of strings in Shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728683/case-insensitive-comparision-of-strings-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bash` case-transformations (`${var,,}` and `${var^^}`) were introduced (some time ago) in bash version 4. However, if you are using Mac OS X, you most likely have bash v3.2 which doesn't implement case-transformation natively.

In that case, you can do lower-cased comparison less efficiently and with a lot more typing using `tr`:

```
if [[ $(tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<<"$arr7") = $(tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<<"$artist") ]]; then
  # ...
fi
```

By the way, `=~` does a regular expression comparison, not a string comparison. You almost certainly wanted `=`. Also, instead of `[[ $x -lt $y ]]` you can use an arithmetic compound command: `(( x < y ))`. (In arithmetic expansions, it is not necessary to use `$` to indicate variables.)

Comment: says tr: Illegal Byte sequence

Comment: Either the quotes (which I just added in the answer) are really necessary, or you are using an even older operating system. What platform are you using?

Comment: Even wth the quotes it says the same

Answer (score 11):

Bash has a builtin method for converting strings to lower case.  Once they are both lower case, you can compare them for equality.  For example:

```
$ arr7="Rolling Stones"
$ artist="rolling stoneS"
$ [ "${arr7,,}" = "${artist,,}" ] && echo "Matches!"
Matches!
$ [[ ${arr7,,} =~ ${artist,,} ]] && echo "Matches!"
Matches!
```

#### Details

`${parameter,,}` converts all characters in a string to lower case.  If you wanted to convert to upper case, use `${parameter^^}`.  If you want to convert just some of the characters, use `${parameter,,pattern}` where only those characters matching `pattern` are changed.  Still more details on this are documented by `man`bash`:

> ${parameter^pattern}
>   ${parameter^^pattern} 
>   ${parameter,pattern} 
>   ${parameter,,pattern}
>
> **Case modification.**  This expansion modifies the case of alphabetic characters in parameter.  The pattern is expanded to
>   produce a pattern just
>                 as in pathname expansion.  The ^ operator converts lowercase letters matching pattern to uppercase; the , operator
>   converts matching uppercase
>                 letters to lowercase.  The ^^ and ,, expansions convert each matched character in the expanded value; the ^ and , expansions
>   match and convert
>                 only the first character in the expanded value.  If pattern is omitted, it is treated like a ?, which matches every
>   character.   If  parameter
>                 is  @  or  *,  the  case  modification operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.  If
>                 parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the case modification operation is applied to each member of the array
>   in  turn,  and
>                 the expansion is the resultant list.

#### Compatibility

These case modification methods require `bash` version 4 (released on 2009-Feb-20) or better.

Comment: It says bad subtitution

Comment: Still says bad substitution

Comment: This is the message that you would see if you are not actually running it under `bash`.  Please give me all the gory details about this happened.  Did you try it at the command line or was it in a script?  If it was in a script, how did you launch the script?

Comment: Did it in a script and ran it using this
./script1.sh million_songs_metadata.csv "Johnny Cash" 1970 1983

Comment: This is the if loop now : if [[ $arr11 -gt $from_year ]] && [[ $arr11 -lt $to_year ]] && [[ ${arr7,,} =~ ${artist,,} ]]

Comment: Just to be sure that we are running bash, try `bash ./script1.sh million_songs_metadata.csv "Johnny Cash" 1970 1983`.  Also, when an error occurs, bash should tell you the line on the script on which it occurred.  Which line matches up with that line number?

Comment: At the command prompt, enter and run as a single line: `arr7=Cash; artist=caSH; [[ ${arr7,,} =~ ${artist,,} ]] && echo yes`.  It should return `yes`.  If it doesn't try:  `bash -c 'arr7=Cash; artist=caSH; [[ ${arr7,,} =~ ${artist,,} ]] && echo yes'` and tell me what happens.

Comment: Bad substitution again :(

Comment: I am testing these on my machine and they all work for me.  For each of the three separate tests I suggested, please report on the _complete and exact_ message for each one.

Comment: Just says ${arr7,,}: bad substitution

Comment: Are you on OSX using bash v3.2 as @rici suggests?

Comment: dont know which version..i am using mac

Answer (score 1):

Use `shopt -s nocasematch`

**demo**

```
#!/bin/bash

words=(Cat dog mouse cattle scatter)


#Print words from list that match pat
print_matches()
{
    pat=$1
    echo "Pattern to match is '$pat'"
    for w in "${words[@]}"
    do
        [[ $w =~ $pat ]] &&  echo "$w"
    done
    echo
}

echo -e "Wordlist: (${words[@]})\n"

echo "Normal matching"
print_matches 'cat'
print_matches 'Cat'

echo -e "-------------------\n"

echo "Case-insensitive matching"
shopt -s nocasematch

print_matches 'cat'
print_matches 'CAT'

echo -e "-------------------\n"

echo "Back to normal matching"
shopt -u nocasematch

print_matches 'cat'
```

**output**

```
Wordlist: (Cat dog mouse cattle scatter)

Normal matching
Pattern to match is 'cat'
cattle
scatter

Pattern to match is 'Cat'
Cat

-------------------

Case-insensitive matching
Pattern to match is 'cat'
Cat
cattle
scatter

Pattern to match is 'CAT'
Cat
cattle
scatter

-------------------

Back to normal matching
Pattern to match is 'cat'
cattle
scatter
```