# Why is my shell script giving the same output for every case?

Tags: string, bash, shell, compare

The question was to write a script that checks whether the character read is "Y", "y","n" or "N", and display the result accordingly.

However, I'm getting the output YES for every input I give. I'm a complete novice in scripting and can't figure out what might be causing this.

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read CHAR

if [ [$CHAR=="Y"] -o [$CHAR=="y"] ]; then
        echo "YES"
elif [ [$CHAR=="N"] -o [$CHAR=="n"] ]; then
        echo "NO"
fi
```

Comment: Avoid `ALL_CAPS` variables. They are, by convention, reserved for the shell/etc. to use.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets do not work like parenthesis in `test` expressions. Also, `test` uses `=`, not `==`. And you also need to split to expressions properly into tokens (by adding spaces around the `=` signs). So what you want, rather, is this:

```
if [ "$CHAR" = Y -o "$CHAR" = y ]; then
    echo "YES"
elif [ "$CHAR" = N -o "$CHAR" = n ]; then
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Notice that I've also quoted `"$CHAR"`. This makes the program more robust in the cases where `$CHAR` is empty or contains spaces. The `Y` and `N`, on the other hand, do not need any quoting as they are constants and contain no whitespace.

To be more precise, what happens in your program as that each of the `$CHAR` expressions expand to a single token that looks something like `[N==Y]`, which is a token without special significance for `test`. Any token that lacks special significance is interpreted by `test` as a "true".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single `=` for string comparison and you've too many brackets. So the code becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
read CHAR

if [ "$CHAR" = "Y" -o "$CHAR" = "y" ]; then
  echo "YES"
elif [ "$CHAR" = "N" -o "$CHAR"="n" ]; then
  echo "NO"
fi
```

Next time when you'd like to debug your script why it doesn't work, run is as: `bash -x ./script.sh` or add `-x` in your first line after `bash`.

---

Check the following one-liner:

```
read CHAR && [ "${CHAR^^}" = "Y" ] && echo YES || echo NO
```

It's using [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), see: [Case Insensitive comparision of strings in Shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1728683/55075).

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. But can you explain the significance of correct spacing in scripting? I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @ZeWisdom It's just cleaner and easier to read and more towards common coding standards, so it's a good practice. Secondly sometimes bash fails when you don't put a space between expressions, like right next to the brackets (`[`, `]`).

Comment: That's because `[` isn't a shell syntax thing. It is a command (see `ls /usr/bin[` for example) and so it needs to be its own word to work correctly. You wouldn't expect `echo"$CHAR"` to work would you?

Answer (score 1):

a case statement can be quite readable

```
read char
case ${char,} in
  y*) echo Yes;;
  n*) echo No;;
esac
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: bash 4+ only for lower-casing expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read "CHAR"

if [[ "$CHAR" == "Y" || "$CHAR" == "y" ]]; then
        echo "YES"
elif [[ "$CHAR" == "N" || "$CHAR" == "n" ]]; then
        echo "NO"
fi
```

Try this out!
The problem seems to be the usage of "-o" with double "=", and the spaces in if and elif for the parenthesis.