# How can I do case-insensitive string comparison in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

My script:

```
echo "input yes or no"
read a
if [ $a = "yes" ] or [ $a = "Yes" ] or [ $a = "YES" ];
then
    command
else
    command
done
```

I have an idea that I will convert the answer (using the `tr A-Z a-z` command) first and after that compare with string... is that okay?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting

Comment: Dear stalet

Thanks for your link
I also wrote that i can convert first, but i want to know more solutions :D

Comment: This question have already been answered here: [Case Insensitive comparision of strings in Shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728683/case-insensitive-comparision-of-strings-in-shell-script)

Comment: Check `make 1 dialog`. E.g. https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/A_yes/no_dialog_box

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example on how to do it without conversion in bash 4.
You can use parameter expansion to inline change the value of the `$a` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "input yes or no"
read a
if [ ${a,,} = "yes" ];
then
    echo "test 1"
else
    echo "test 2"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mr.stalet

Answer (score 8):

You can use `shopt -s nocasematch`.

Try this :

```
shopt -s nocasematch
echo "Input yes or no"
read a
if [[ $a == "yes" ]]
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

From `bash`:

> nocasematch
>
> If set, Bash matches patterns in a case-insensitive fashion when
>   performing matching while executing case or [[ conditional commands.

Comment: Thanks you so much, mr.sat

Comment: Do you need to unset before exit the script ? Or is it set only for the current script ?

Comment: @Flows, This will set only for current script/shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dialog` tool available on most systems, which can display an interactive dialog in the console:

```
if dialog  --title example1 --backtitle example2 --yesno "Make a choice!" 7 60
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Bypasses the case-sensitivity of the user input completely.

[More examples.](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php)