# how to construct regex to compare case insensitive strings in shell script?

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell

I am passing command line arguments to a shell script and it is being compared aganist a regular expression. The following code is case-sensitive:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^(cat)|(dog)$ ]] && echo "match" || echo "no match"
```

How can I modify this regex that will ignore cases? I would be able to pass `cAt` and it should match.

I want to use `/i` regex flag as it ignores cases. But how do I use it inside a shell script? I have tried `[[ $1 =~ /(cat)|(dog)/i ]]` but the script exited with a syntax error.

[StackOverflow has a similar question but it does not answer my inquiry.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728683/case-insensitive-comparison-of-strings-in-shell-script) I want to use `test` to compare both strings and not interested to use `shopt -s nocasematch` or `grep <expression>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use

```
shopt -s nocasematch
```

before your command.

alternatively

```
shopt -s nocasematch && [[ 'doG' =~ (cat)|(dog) ]] && echo 'hi' || echo 'no match'
```

Comment: Asker said that he does not want to use `shopt -s nocasematch` :/